# Preprocessing exponent of const number

Tags: c, preprocessor

My issue: I want to get an id with N_DIGITS digits and I would like N_DIGITS to be customizable at preprocessing. My id is an integer so I want to define 10^N_DIGITS as the maximum of this number.

In other words: is it possible to preprocess a number with a macro as exponent?

Here is my ultimate attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N_DIGITS 5
#define MAX_N    10e ## N_DIGITS

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", MAX_N);
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, this doesn't work and the error is `error: exponent has no digits`.
I don't see why the principle could not be implemented since everything is known by the compiler but I might be wrong.

Anyway my syntax is incorrect, can I get some help here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Token pasting is done before macro expansion, so you will get `10eN_DIGITS` which isn't a valid token.

What you can do is have two levels of a function-like macro - one level to do the macro expansion followed by another one to do the pasting:

```
#define N_DIGITS 5
#define MAKE_EXPONENT2(exp) 10e ## exp
#define MAKE_EXPONENT(exp) MAKE_EXPONENT2(exp)
#define MAX_N    MAKE_EXPONENT(N_DIGITS)
```

This makes `MAX_N` expand to `10e5`.

Other issues:

- 10e5 is a `double` constant so needs to be printed with `%f`, not `%d`.
- If you want 10 to the power of 5 then you need 1e5 rather than 10e5.
- Using a floating-point constant to deal with integer data may cause in loss of precision.

Comment: Thank  you very much for the answer and the warnings. I'm not sure to understand what's behind "macro expansion" and "token pasting" but this solution works as I expected. I will investigate more

Comment: Does a cast of a double literal to an `int` at compile time work?

Comment: @thebusybee It will work on most platforms, but casting to a 64-bit integer may lose precision because `double` can't accurately represent all its values.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
#define N_DIGITS 4

#if N_DIGITS == 1
#define MAX_N    1
#elif N_DIGITS == 2
#define MAX_N    10
#elif N_DIGITS == 3
#define MAX_N    100
#elif N_DIGITS == 4
#define MAX_N    1000
#elif N_DIGITS == 5
#define MAX_N    10000
#else
#error N_DIGITS not in [1..5]
#endif
```

It's not very elegant, but at least you get integer constants and not floating point constants.